# LaTeX tufte-book how to wrap around chapter, section, subsection heading

Tags: sectioning, formatting, tufte

I am writing a book using the package `tufte-book`. Some of my chapter titles and section titles are too long. But I don't know how to get it to wrap around instead of going into the margins and off the page. The code is below. I suspect it has to do with the `\begin{fullwidth}` command but I am not sure.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}%
      [display]% shape
      {\relax\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\begin{fullwidth}}{}}% format applied to label+text
      {\itshape
    \thechapter}% label
      {0pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
      {\Large\rmfamily\allcaps}% before the title body
      [\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\end{fullwidth}}{}]% after the title body

    \titleformat{\section}%
      [hang]% shape
      {\normalfont\large\itshape}% format applied to label+text
      {\thesection}% label
      {1em}% horizontal separation between label and title body
      {}% before the title body
      []% after the title body

    \titleformat{\subsection}%
      [hang]% shape
      {\normalfont\large\itshape}% format applied to label+text
      {\thesubsection}% label
      {1em}% horizontal separation between label and title body
      {}% before the title body
      []% after the title body
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please add a full  [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what packages etc you need to get your code to work (but don't add code that is not needed). This makes it much easier for people to help you. In this it would be good to have the document class information, together with all relevant `\usepackage{...}` commands and some examples of your long titles. The MWE example should compile when you run it through LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\titleformat{\chapter}%
      [display]% shape
      {\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}% format applied to label+text
      {\itshape
    \thechapter}% label
      {0pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
      {\Large\rmfamily\allcaps}% before the title body
      [\end{minipage}]% after the title body
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{A somehow very long title that goes right into the margins}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

You will need to change the `fullwidth` environment to a `minipage` as shown in the code above. A `MWE` should have this format.